# Undefined method 'array' for main:Object

Tags: ruby, arrays, undefined

So I was just playing with blocks in ruby, and I wrote this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

def my_map ary
    a = ary.clone
    if block_given?
        while element = a.shift
            yield element
        end
    else
        ary
    end
end

array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

my_map array { |e|
    puts e * 2
}

p array
```

But it keeps giving me this error:

```
./tests.rb:16:in `<main>': undefined method `array' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

Why is that? I can clearly see that I defined array. I would appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When passing an argument and a multi-line block, you have to put the argument between braces

```
my_map(array) { |e|
  puts e * 2
}
```

or use a do end block

```
my_map array do |e|
  puts e * 2
end
```

Anyway this one-line block looks the best approach for this case:

```
my_map(array) { |e| puts e * 2 }
```

Comment: the one-liner would fail if the params is not in parens

Answer (score 2):

The Ruby interpreter parses:

```
my_map array { |e|
    puts e * 2
}
```

as:

```
my_map(array ( { |e| puts e * 2 } ) )
```

which explains, why it thinks array should be a method, to avoid that change:

```
my_map array { |e|
    puts e * 2
}
```

to:

```
my_map(array) { |e|
    puts e * 2
}
```

or:

```
my_map array do |e|
    puts e * 2
end
```

the curly braces are meant for one-liner blocks and should be avoided for multi-line blocks

Comment: Since `{` is used for both hashes and blocks, the parser can get tripped up if it doesn't know which one to expect.

Comment: @tadman it does not expect a hash, as an hash there would come as an argument which does not occur without a comma

Comment: Ah, right, it's parsing as `my_map(array { |e| ... })` vs. the expected `my_map(array) { |e| ... }`. I tend to use brackets pretty rigorously to avoid this ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
my_map(array) { |e|
    puts e * 2
}
```